# New Update of google maps app doesnt display a mark that i create in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, android-4.2-jelly-bean

HI Im using a intent to send to a google maps a position via geo: with his latitude and longitude and mark a position with a titles. but know that i update the google maps v7.0.1 on android 4.2.2 it wont display the mark that i did in the code.  here is the code that i used for make the call of maps.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
        Uri.parse("geo:"+latitude+","+longitude+"?q="+latitude+","+longitude+"("+name+")"));
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity"));
                startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that it is not supported any more.
Also this syntax is not mentioned in [Google Uris](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html), [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) or [geo: Uri Draft](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4).

If google maps does not find the given name at this point, there will be no search result. You can remove the name and google maps will draw a marker at the given point with its street name.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
    Uri.parse("geo:"+latitude+","+longitude+"?q="+latitude+","+longitude+"("+name+")"));
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity"));
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
        Uri.parse("geo:"+latitude+","+longitude+"?q="+latitude+","+longitude));
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity"));
                startActivity(intent);   and it works thank you

Comment: It was never mentioned on any of those pages you referred to; it definitely stopped working in Google Maps 7 though.  Disappointing to lose such a useful feature.